# SQL query showing element more than once

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL query but it doesn't entirely work because it shows each element more than once.

```
select c.name, c.director, c.title, count(c.title) as numfilms
from casting c
join casting c1 on c1.name = c.name
Group by c.name, c.director, c.title
Having count (c.title) > 1
order by numfilms
```

So what it does it shows which actors have made more than 1 film. But unfortunately, this query shows each actor as many times as the number of movies he made. Using distinct doesn't work as actor may have been in different movie with same title and different director.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select c.name, count(c.title) as numfilms
from casting c
Group by c.name
Having count (c.title) > 1
order by numfilms
```

If you are just looking for the actors names and the number of films they are in you can remove the title and director from the grouping and select.

EDIT: From reading the comment below clarifying the question Richard's first query should be the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not making sense - the join of casting back to itself is the confusing part- it is completely unnecessary unless you need the full record as shown below.

```
select c1.name, c1.director, c1.title, numfilms
from
(
    select c.name, count(c.title) as numfilms
    from casting c 
    Group by c.name
    Having count (c.title) > 1
) c
join casting c1 on c1.name = c.name
order by c1.name
```

This query shows: for each actor who appears in more than one film, show all the actors' films.

On the other hand, if you are only after actor names who have appeared in more than one film, a single pass through casting is all you need.

```
select c.name, count(c.title) as numfilms
from casting c 
Group by c.name
Having count (c.title) > 1
```

The confusing part is, if you wanted names only, why add the `director` and `title` to the SELECT? Which film of the actor's films to show?

Comment: Will this query not return multiple rows as well? This query will return the films and the directors for each movie the actor has been part of. The wording of the original question could have been a bit better.

Comment: I've just reread my question. Sorry about being a bit too inexplicit. What I have to do is show each actor who played in more than one film and the films he played in. In this case, is my initial query correct? For some reason I thought it was wrong showing, something like the following: actor1 film1 director 1 count; actor1 film2 director2 count.

Comment: Ok so with the clarification of the issue Richard's first query will be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Sorin Your query should **also** work, but will be slower because it is first exploding the result set then grouping for the counts.